# Galleon says transactions have been completed when they don't show up on block explorers

Tags: tezos-client, galleon

I have tried several operations in Galleon (0.9.3b) and am getting very odd things.

1 - I tried creating a new delegate address, and in Galleon the transaction says Pending... However, if I click on the link to open the transaction in Mininax.com, the URL says: 
ZdJ9pN9:nbranch%20refused%20(Error:n%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20**Counter%2044743%20already%20used%20for**%20contract%20tz1LEqdoXejpEu1mVf1uKXhyxqyBCEAorkKp%20(expected%2044744)n)%7D]

2 - I tried sending some XTZ from a manager address to a KT address, and I get the message "Successfully started contract invocation." But again if I click "View on a block explorer", Mininax says "Operation not found or not yet recorded", and the URL also contains: 
https://mininax.io/mainnet/operations/[%7Bkind:temporary,id:failure,msg:Error%20while%20applying%20operation%20opEQbhmUrbbEjjoP7gMbmDGsQiWrgCzV8nWpqwpVumaVDb93ECw:nbranch%20refused%20(Error:n%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20**Counter%2044743%20already%20used**%20for%20contract%20tz1LEqdoXejpEu1mVf1uKXhyxqyBCEAorkKp%20(expected%2044744)n)%7D]

None of these transactions show up on the TzXT or any other block explorers.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

1. Try a [tzstats](https://tzstats.com/) block explorer to see actual transactions. Delegation txns show up under then "other" tab. If your operation/transaction is not recorded here, then it sounds Galleon was underestimating the fee required. Setting the fee to "medium" will fix it.[image]
2. Best to delegate your funds from a 'tz' manager account as this is the way forward post-babylon and the 'tz' transaction fees are lower than sending from a 'KT' account.